# Resolving to Option[Nothing]?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> def f[F[_], A, B](x: F[A], y: F[B]): F[B] = y
f: [F[_], A, B](x: F[A], y: F[B])F[B]
```

How does the output type of the below call evaluate to `Option[Nothing]`?

```
scala> :t f( Option(42), ???)
Option[Nothing]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#conformance This part of the spec is especially useful here.

Take your function:

```
scala> def f[F[_], A, B >: Nothing <: Any](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[B] = fb
f: [F[_], A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])F[B]
```

The compiler sees this as (More or less):

```
scala> def fAnnotated[F[_], A >: Nothing <: Any, B >: Nothing <: Any](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[B] = fb
fAnnotated: [F[_], A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])F[B]
```

So, the compiler infers that your types have a lower bound of Nothing and an upper bound of Any. We can see this in action with your example.

```
scala> :t f(Option(42), ???)
Option[Nothing]
```

And with a contravariant type ctor Any is inferred:

```
scala> trait T[-A]
defined trait T

scala> :t f(new T[Int]{}, ???)
T[Any]
```

The scala compiler looks for the most restrictive version of a type where soundness holds good. As it cannot find B (there really is no such thing as B) it infers Nothing for the invariant and covariant cases and Any for the contravariant case.

Answer (score 0):

See the definition of ???:

```
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError
```

So `F` is `Option` and `B` is `Nothing`, thus your return type is `Option[Nothing]`.

Comment: I'm not sure this really explains why `B` is inferred to be `Nothing`. How you get from the expression `???` to the type `Option[Nothing]` takes a couple more steps.

Comment: I think it's a side effect of how the compiler tries to fit type constructors in the type hierarchy between `Any` and `Nothing`.

Comment: `F[B]` is actually `Nothing`, but `Nothing` is also `Option[Nothing]`, which certainly helps the compiler find a least upper-bound of `Option` for `F`.